# Apache Solr 6.6.2 in SolrCloud mode, not working for new replica

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper

I have installed Apache Solr 6.6.2 on 2 different systems and I have to run Solr in Cloud mode that I have done successfully. Now I want to create one shard with 2 replica. For that I have run following command

```
bin/solr create -c myCollection -d use_configs -n conf1 -replicationFactor 2
```

At the time of above command execution, there was only one node live, so it creates one replicat and all index data reside in corresponding Solr Home. When I start second solr (on seperate machine), It replicate index to second machine also (it was expected due to replication factor 2). But After that I have to replace second machine with a new one. I did the same setting and run below command on new machine

```
bin/solr start -cloud -s tmp/solr -p 7900 -z zk-ip:2181
```

Solr on new machine starts successfully but it does not replicate index to this new machine. Is there any configuration I missed on this new system ?
Also in admin dashboard, it shows that only one replica (system) is available on first system but there is no indication for second system. Why solr is behaving like this ? I think if I add a new system then index should be replicated to this new system as I have set replication factor to 2 at time of creation of the shard.

Comment: Did you actually remove the replica from the collection, or did you just stop the server? There's an explicit `REPLACENODE` command to replace an existing node with a new one.

Comment: Let me check this command as I have not tested it till now

Comment: If you've just stopped the replica and haven't done anything else, Solr will still expect that it reappears when you restart the node.